# Added adsense html code but it shows twice

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I added these element on my page:

```
  <script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-000000000000" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block; text-align:center;" data-ad-layout="in-article" data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000000" data-ad-slot="00000000000"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

and it shows 2 ads even though I only added 1 html block code, anyone can help?

Comment: `<script async="">` is incorrect. It should be either `<script async>` or `<script async="async">`.

Comment: Check if auto ads disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` by itself.

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-3356097185125788"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```